# Catch2 Unit Tests - could not find env executable

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch2

So I am currently writing a catch2 unit test for my c++ program and getting to know the basics of Unit tests, but I encountered the following problem with the following code(./tests being my executable for the tests:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(memory)

include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
# Executable
add_executable(arrays
            src/main.cpp
)

# Fetch Catch2
Include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        Catch2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
        GIT_TAG        v3.3.2
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)

# Build Tests
enable_testing()
add_executable(tests
        src/arrays.test.cpp

)
target_link_libraries(tests PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
target_include_directories(tests PRIVATE src/)

# Register Tests
add_test(tests env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 ./tests)
```

I get the following error:

`Unable to find executable: env Could not find executable env`

I would be glad if someone could help me. Btw, I am coding on CLion

I already tried it with different parameters but no results sadly.

Comment: remove `env` from `add_test` but for the way you're supposed to do it see https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md#customization

Comment: so first of all, thank you. But I followed the tutorial on the git but now I get the error "tests were not found". What could be the source of this?

Comment: and also, removing env also didnt work, it then forces the next parameter to be the variable for the executable, so it searches for CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 as an executable

Comment: Prefixing commands with environment variables is a posix thing, it doesn't work on Windows